# Adding parent and child to Kendo UI controller using MVC 5

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using MVC 5 with Kendo UI(Latest Version) and SQL Server 2014, and I want to add a treeview controller that will display parent items and child items when users click on the parent item. I have two classes:

1.Category

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProductTreeView.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2.Product

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ProductTreeView.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Products(int? id)
{
    var model = db.Categories
            .Select(p => new {
                id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                hasChildren = p.Products.Any()
            });
        return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the HTML looks like this:

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="k-label-top">TreeView</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("treeview")
        .DataSource(datasource => datasource
             .Read(read => read.Action("Products", "Categories"))
        ).DataTextField("Name")
        )
    </div>
</div>
```

The result is parent items within parent items, looping.
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdoGP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a self referencing example you might use for employees/managers. You need the more classical way where you provide the child products in a collection.

```
public ActionResult Products(int? id)
{
    var model = db.Categories
            .Select(p => new {
                id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                hasChildren = p.Products.Any(),
                Children = p.Products
            });
        return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then something like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().Name("treeview")
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m => m
            .Id("Id")
            .HasChildren("hasChildren")
            .Children("Children"))
        .Read(r => r.Action("Products", "Categories")))
    .DataTextField("Name"))
```

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/local-data-binding

Comment: Your solution worked with a little modification after getting a circular reference while serializing object. In the Products controller action I added the following line. //return this.Json(from obj in model select new { Id = obj.id, Name = obj.Name}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });

            return Content(list, "application/json");

Comment: I had a model that didn't have the same properties as TreeViewItem, this helped me display the tree using my custom objects instead.  Thank you.